# Dual dual, dual disk, how to recover after linux disk failure

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

Installed Windows 10 on one disk.
Installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a separate disk and set up dual boot: everything was working.
Now Ubuntu disk appears to have died: not even visible in the BIOS/UEFI.
Boot just gives a grub> prompt.
A replacement disk arrives tomorrow.

Is it just a simple case of installing Ubuntu on this new disk (I have a bootable USB I can use) to get back to a dual boot system, or are there any other steps I'll need to do?

Answer (score 0):

I do assume that a windows update re-wrote the EFI partition
Windows will overwrite the boot sector whenever you install it, upgrade it to a new version, or use tools like `bootrec /fixmbr`, `bootrec /fixboot`, or the older `fdisk /mbr`. [source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68587)

WARNING: This Only works for EFI

Use a Live Ubuntu USB and choose *try live* instead of *install*.
Open GParted to determine the names of the following partitions

1. The EFI partition. (filesystem: FAT, size: 100MB-500MB)
2. You Ubuntu partition. (filesystem: ext4, size: ?????)

If you want to use the terminal (which I believe is ALOT easier), open a terminal with CTRL+ALT+T.

type the following

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

You should get an output similar to the following: (I will ignore other partitions)

```
/dev/sda1      2048    206847    204800  100M EFI System <========    
/dev/sda3 527517696 554121215  26603520 12.7G Linux filesystem <=======
```

Device name can also be `/dev/nvmen1pXX` if you use nvme drives

I will assume that EFI partition is `/dev/sda1` and Ubuntu is `/dev/sda2`
Type the following in a terminal:

### Chrooting

```
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt 
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi
sudo mount –bind /dev /mnt/dev                                                                 
sudo mount –bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts                                                         
sudo mount –bind /proc /mnt/proc                                                               
sudo mount –bind /sys /mnt/sys                                                                 
sudo chroot /mnt
```

### Fixing Grub

Install GRUB with

```
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootloader-id=GRUB
```

Generate Grub-config
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg

That should fix grub, you can now exit with `exit` or `Ctl+D` and reboot.

Note: you might need to update BIOS boot order

## Preventing windows from doing this again

I don't use windows so I can't help, but you SHOULD stop windows from re-writing your EFI partition.